# Does the Nap spell allow a Psionicist to fully recover PSP?

Tags: spells, psionics, adnd-2e

I thought so, because it lets even mages memorize spells, but some people at the hobby shop yesterday spoke against it.

Does a psionicist affected by the 2nd level *Tome of Magic* cleric spell *nap* recover their PSP?

Answer (score 5):

Let's just blow some dust off the old 2nd ed books and...

From *nap* in the *Tome of Magic*:

> Creatures affected by this spell are put to sleep
>   for one hour. Upon awakening, the creature is as
>   refreshed as if he had slept for eight hours. The
>   affected person recovers lost hit points as if he
>   rested for a full night. Wizards can memorize
>   spells as if real time had passed.

From *The Complete Psionics Handbook*:

> A character who has expended psionic strength points can recover those points by "taking it easy"- which means engaging in no hard physical activity and refraining from using psionic powers (i.e. from expending any more PSPs).  After each *hour* in which a character expends no psionic strength points, check Table 6 to determine how many PSPs the character recovers.

I'll just include the relevant line from Table 6:

> Rejuvenating, sleeping       12/hour (2/turn)

And one more quote that I think is most relevant, same book:

> PSPs are similar to hit points,
>   except that the psionicist spends them willingly,
>   and he can recover them much faster
>   than lost hit points.

Right away you can say that your psionicist would at least gain 12 PSP from the spell, because no matter what they are definitively asleep for 1 hour.  You can further make a *very* strong argument that your psionicist would regain 96 PSP, the effects of 8 hours sleep, because according to our quotes up there, PSP are treated similarly to hit points, which are *also* recovered during *nap*- nowhere does it say that PSPs are the only thing unaffected.

The people at the hobby shop may try to argue that it isn't RAW, because, granted, the spell doesn't mention PSPs specifically.  Then again, psionics are only mentioned once in *Tome of Magic*, and both it and the *Expanded Psionics Handbook* came out the same year, so it's entirely possible that that *nap* was written before TSR decided on the revisions to psionics that the *Handbook* represents (I wouldn't know that for sure, but its a good conjecture)